# How to check what servers your Discord Bot is in [discord.js]

Tags: discord.js, bots

How would I check what servers my discord bot is in, code wise in discordjs.
And able to join those servers.

Comment: Hi, you should [edit] your question by adding a [mcve] :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can view the guilds (servers) your bot is in with `<Client>#guilds`. Example:

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

console.log(bot.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild.id));

bot.login('YOUR_TOKEN');
```

This will return an array of the ids  of the guilds your bot is a member of.

Comment: _"This will return an array of the ids of the guilds your bot is a member of"_ No, this won't. It will probably return an unusable `GuildManager`.